# As author of AGPL / GPL project, do I need to keep previous versions, or only current one?

Tags: licensing, gpl, source-code, agpl

As author of AGPL / GPL project, do I need to keep previous versions, or only current one?

For example I made and published 50 versions of the project (via git). Can I delete previous modifications and keep only latest version?

Comment: Have you accepted contributions from anyone else, or are you the sole rightsholder?

Comment: I had. So will I need to remove those contributions from source code?

Comment: Have you distributed binaries or other non-source versions of the software? You are required to provide the Corresponding Source for binaries, but this might not require retaining old versions.

Comment: @amon Corresponding Source means the source for that binary which you distributed/conveyed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you've been careful to keep *all* the copyright notices that were added for contributors (as well as your own) I think you are fine to cease distribution of earlier versions.  One is under no obligation to distribute software one has received under GPL; the requirement is only that if you do distribute it, you must do so under the required terms.